# JPA multiselect error

Tags: hibernate, jpa, fetch, multi-select

Getting below error when doing multiselect on tables, to fetch the selected columns only:

```
Root<MainTrade> mt= criteriaQuery.from(MainTrade.class);
mt.fetch("etrade",JOIN_TYPE.INNER).fetch("addressList",JOIN_TYPE.INNER);

criteriaQuery.multiselect(mt.get("tradeId"),mt.get("etrade").get("addressList");

Model classes are as below:

Class MainTrade{

@Id
private Integer tradeId;
.....
....
@OneToOne
private ETrade etrade;

}

Class ETrade
{

private Integer tradeId;

@Id
private Integer eTradeId;

@OneToMany
private List<Address> addressList;

}

Class Address
{

 private Integer eTradeId;
 private String streetName
}
```

Getting error on multiselect:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join
>   fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in
>   the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch
>   join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias1......]